# Converting ResultSet map to HTML table for email

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am building a Spring Boot application that runs SQL select queries. I have managed to save the output and display it. Now I want to convert this output to an table in HTML and send it via an email.

I am stuck at the part where you convert it to html. I've read a few things about Thymeleaf. I think I somehow need to parse my map to the `generateMailHtml` method, but maybe I am thinking to hard. How could I solve this? Could be with Thymeleaf or something else.

```
public void resultSet(Exchange exchange) {

    Connection connection = null;
    Map < String, List < nl.placeholder.databasemailer.ResultSet >> valueMap;
    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        List < Map < String, Object >> rows = new ArrayList < Map < String, Object >> ();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select bridgeid, containername from baseintegrationheaders");
        //valueMap = new HashMap<>();
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Map < String, Object > columns = new LinkedHashMap < String, Object > ();

            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                columns.put(md.getColumnLabel(i), rs.getObject(i));
            }
            rows.add(columns);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(columns);
            System.out.println(columns);
        }
        exchange.getIn().setBody(rows);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String generateMailHtml(String text) {
    Map < String, Object > variables = new HashMap < > ();
    variables.put("mailtext", text);
    final String templateFileName = "mail";
    String output = this.templateEngine.process(templateFileName, new Context(Locale.getDefault(), variables));
    return output;
}
```

This is my template so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div>
    <table
            class="
        table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive-xl
      "
    >
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>BridgeId</th>
            <th>RequestType</th>
            <th>RequestSpecification</th>
            <th>FaultDescription</th>
            <th>SourceSystem</th>
            <th>EventId</th>
            <th>MessageId</th>
            <th>RelatesTo</th>
            <th>SysTimeStamp</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="rows :${rows}">
            <td>
                [[${rows.date}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.bridgeid}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.requesttype}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.requestspecification}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.faultdescription}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.sourcesystem}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.eventid}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.messageid}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.relatesto}]]
            </td>
            <td>
                [[${rows.systimestamp}]]
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your Thymeleaf template look like?

Comment: @CardinalSystem apologies, I've just added my template.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using is quite complex. I would suggest to create an object based on the result set and use that object in thymeleaf.

When doing `[[${row.bridgeid}]]`, it is actually invoking the getter method on the object as such `row.getBridgeid()`. But in your case, you have a map of column name against the data in that column and the approach `[[${row.bridgeid}]]` will not work unless you have an object with that getter method.

It can be quite nasty to navigate through that dataset.

I have created a very simple project which passes a list of `Person` objects to the thymeleaf context. The `email.html` page uses that data to populate the table view.

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private LocalDate dateRegistered;

    public Person(String name, int age, LocalDate dateRegistered) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dateRegistered = dateRegistered;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateRegistered() {
        return dateRegistered;
    }
}
```

The email template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date registered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="row : ${personsInThymeleaf}">
            <td>[[${row.name}]]</td>
            <td>[[${row.age}]]</td>
            <td>[[${row.dateRegistered}]]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Processing of the data in thymeleaf.

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    persons.add(new Person("John", 65, LocalDate.now()));
    persons.add(new Person("Alex", 43, LocalDate.now()));
    persons.add(new Person("Pam", 23, LocalDate.now()));

    Context context = new Context();
    // using personsInThymeleaf to have a different variable name in the thymeleaf engine
    context.setVariable("personsInThymeleaf", persons);

    String message = templateEngine.process("email", context);

    System.out.println(message);
```

You can find the code at https://github.com/lsungum/th-email.git and run it.

If you are already using spring, it is worth looking into spring data jpa. This way you do not have to deal with the low level details of querying the database.